# NameError: name 'data' is not defined while using data for specifying length of dataset

Tags: python-2.7

I am getting an error for name data is not defined

I tried to initialize it with some value which didn't work

```
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
train=pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\samplecode\\questions.xlsx')
test=pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\samplecode\\test2.xlsx')
print(train.shape,test.shape)
train.head()
print(len(data.question_text[data['target'] == 0]) /      len(data['question_text']) * 100,'percent of sincere')
print(len(data.question_text[data['target'] == 1]) / len(data['question_text']) * 100,'percent of insincere')
```

> `NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>       <ipython-input-4-04400b61b36d> in <module>()
>       ----> 1 print(len(data.question_text[data['target'] == 0]) /      len(data['question_text']) * 100,'percent of sincere')
>             2 print(len(data.question_text[data['target'] == 1]) / len(data['question_text']) * 100,'percent of insincere')`
>
> NameError: name 'data' is not defined

​

Comment: You don’t have any variable named ‘data’. Maybe you intended to have ‘train’ where you wrote ‘data’

Comment: If you are new to Python programming (or to programming in general) I would suggest doing some general Python tutorials first rather than jumping right into machine learning. You’re going to run into a lot more errors. You should be able to solve them yourself.

Comment: I am following a tutorial online which gave this error.

Comment: https://medium.com/@navyakanamarlapudi/quora-insincere-question-classification-755233ddc07a